# Откуда в русском языке двойное отрицание?

Tags: стилистика, недопустимая-метка, психология

Если вдуматься, это действительно как-то глупо. Ведь получается, мы отрицаем то, что отрицаем что-то; что, по идее, должно приводить к утверждению.

Например: Не делай никаких фотографий! То есть, **не** нужно делать **никаких** фотографий (то есть, нужно делать фотографии).

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет двойного отрицания, НЕ - отрицательная частица, а НИ усиливает отрицание.

Кроме того, в данном случае  структура усилительного выражения **формальна**: **не** делай **ни**каких (каких-либо, любых) фотографий. Сравнить: Кто знает? **Ни**кто **не** знает.

Пример **двойного отрицания**: не могу не сказать - должен сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможность двойного отрицания заложена в самом языке, и это свойство не одного только русского языка. Прямое грамматическое отрицание с переворотом смысла через повторное применение отрицательных частиц (как в русском) применяется напр. в китайском,  а возможность чисто логического двойного отрицания есть и в других языках. Даже в английском, про который иногда говорят, что двойного отрицания в нём нет, оно применяется - через однократное отрицание глаголов, отрицающих действие (через приставку или внутренний смысл глагола). В вашем примере логического двойного отрицания нет: форма второго отрицания ("никаких") действует как усиление первого (как и в примере из известной английской песни: 'I can't get no satisfaction...' - без усиления с тем же смыслом было бы 'I can't get ...' или 'I can get no...' - логическое отрицание во всех случаях однократно).

Comment: Мне кажется что "I can't get no satisfaction" - не хороший пример, поскольку "лирический герой" этой песни и не претендует на владение литературным английским.

Comment: Эта форма выражения (с повторением отриц. частиц) не из области "неграмотных", скорее, широко распространённая разговорная и диалектная. Где-то в 16 веке и вовсе была нормой. Это действительно, не рекомендуется (здесь второе отрицание легко заменяется на 'any'), но в большинстве случаев это не приводит к недоразумениям. Cкорее, неграмотны попытки выразить этим способом двойное логическое отрицание, для которого существуют абсолютно нормативные формы (напр. 'I'm not unconvinced with what you said.' имеет иной оттенок, чем 'I'm convinced with what you said.' и не "выправляется" такой заменой).